# linux redhat + how to overwrite the existing link quiet mode

Tags: linux, bash, redhat, filesystems, symbolic-link

is it possible to overwrite the exiting link

Without to get fail/error with standard output 1 ?

( like mkdir -p )

```
ls -ltr  /hadoop
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 12 Jun 25 12:51 /hadoop -> /data/hadoop

ln -s   /data/hadoop /hadoop
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/hadoop/hadoop’: File exists
# echo $?
1


ln -sf   /data/hadoop /hadoop
ln: ‘/hadoop/hadoop’: cannot overwrite directory
```

expected output

```
ln -s (extra flags?)   /data/hadoop /hadoop
# echo $?
0
```

Comment: man ln is your best friend

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the -nf option:

`ln -snf   /data/hadoop /hadoop`

Comment: not works see my update!

Comment: can you try to add -n also?

Comment: Why is this answer accepted when it does not solve the issue?

Comment: -nsf solved it as he said